# Erro ao exportar parra o excel

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse abaixo é meu controller.

```
 public function atletaExport(AtletaModalidadeRequest $request){


    $alunosModalidade = $this->alunoequipes->alunosModalidadeFase($request->get('modalidade'),$request->get('fase1'), $request->get('municipio'), 
                                                                  $request->get('regional'), $request->get('sexo'), 
                                                                  $request->get('categoria'))->get();
    //dd($alunosModalidade);



    \Excel::create('AtletasModalidades', function ($excel) use ($alunosModalidade) {


        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function ($sheet) use ($alunosModalidade) {

            $sheet->loadView('relatorios.atletaexport')->with('alunosModalidade', $$alunosModalidade);

        });

    })->download('xlsx');

}
```

Abaixo onde ele faz a coleta das informações

```
    public function atletasModalidade(AtletaModalidadeRequest $request)
{
    $v['title'] = 'Atletas por Modalidade';

    if (Auth::user()->perfil_id == Perfil::ESCOLA) {
        Notification::error('Acesso não permitido.');
        return back()->withInput();
    }

    $fase_id = $request->input('fase1');
    $municipio_id = $request->input('municipio');
    $regional_id = $request->input('regional');

    $modalidade_id = $request->input('modalidade');
    $v['sexo'] = $request->input('sexo');
    $v['categoria'] = $request->input('categoria');

    $v['fase'] = $this->fase->find($fase_id);

    $v['local'] = null;
    $v['municipio'] = false;
    $v['regional'] = false;


    $modalidade = $this->modalidade->find($modalidade_id);
    $v['modalidade'] = $modalidade;

    if($municipio_id != '') {
        $v['local'] = $this->municipio->find($municipio_id);
        $v['municipio'] = true;
    }

    if($regional_id != '') {
        //$v['local'] = $this->regional->find($regional_id);
        $v['regional'] = true;
    }

    $v['municipio_id'] = $municipio_id;
    $v['regional_id'] = $regional_id;




    return view('relatorios.atletasModalidade', $v);

}
```

aqui é minha consulta

```
 public function alunosModalidadeFase ($modalidade_id, $fase_id,$municipio,$regional,$sexo, $categoria)
{

    $alunos = $this->join('equipes','equipes.id','=','aluno_equipe.equipe_id')
        ->join('escolas','escolas.id','=','equipes.escola_id')
        ->join('alunos','alunos.id','=','aluno_equipe.aluno_id')
        ->join('municipios','municipios.id','=','escolas.municipio_id')
        ->join('dirigente_fase', 'dirigente_fase.id','=','equipes.tecnico_id')
        ->leftJoin('dirigentes', 'dirigentes.id', '=','dirigente_fase.dirigente_id')
        ->join('fases', 'fases.id', '=', 'equipes.fase_id')
        ->where('equipes.modalidade_id','=',$modalidade_id)
        ->where('fases.id','=',$fase_id);
    if($sexo)
    {
        $alunos = $alunos->where('equipes.sexo','=',$sexo);
    }

    if($categoria)
    {
        $alunos = $alunos->where('equipes.categoria','=',$categoria);
    }

    if($municipio)
    {
        $alunos = $alunos->where('escolas.municipio_id','=',$municipio);
    }

    if($regional)
    {
        $alunos = $alunos->where('municipios.regional_id','=',$regional);
    }

    $alunos = $alunos->select('alunos.nome','alunos.data_nascimento','alunos.sexo',
                              'equipes.categoria as categoria','escolas.nome as escola','dirigentes.nome as tecnico','municipios.nome as municipio')
        ->orderBy('municipios.nome')
        ->orderBy('escolas.nome')
        ->orderBy('alunos.nome')
        ->get();

    return $alunos;
```

e finalizando minha blade de exportação

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome Aluno</th>
      <th>Data Nasc</th>
      <th>Sexo</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Escola</th>
      <th>Técnico</th>
      <th>Município</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($alunosModalidade as $alunoModalidade)
        <tr>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->nome }}</td>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->data_nascimento }}</td>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->sexo }}</td>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->categoria }}</td>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->escola }}</td>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->tecnico}}</td>
          <td >{{ $alunoModalidade->municipio }}</td>
       </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Passo os 6 parâmetros mas mesmo assim ele espera um na função `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ta um pouco complicado de entender onde ta o erro. Uma coisa que reparei que não esta fazendo sentido são os dois `->get` que estão usando.

```
 $alunosModalidade = $this->alunoequipes->alunosModalidadeFase($request->get('modalidade'),$request->get('fase1'), $request->get('municipio'), 
                                                                  $request->get('regional'), $request->get('sexo'), 
                                                                  $request->get('categoria'))->get();
```

Reparei que aqui você está dando um `->get()` no final. E la no seu model:

```
$alunos = $alunos->select('alunos.nome','alunos.data_nascimento','alunos.sexo',
                              'equipes.categoria as categoria','escolas.nome as escola','dirigentes.nome as tecnico','municipios.nome as municipio')
        ->orderBy('municipios.nome')
        ->orderBy('escolas.nome')
        ->orderBy('alunos.nome')
        ->get();

    return $alunos;
```

Você deu outro `->get()`. Ou seja no final ta saindo `$alunos->get()->get()`. 
Da uma reduzida na função de model, substitui por `$alunos::find(1)` e traz um resultado e transforma para o Excel. Tem que ir eliminando código até achar qual parte está errando.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi muito obrigado pela ajuda.